Adding typography and other style related controls in element ui vue js
I am working on a wordpress plugin which is made in vue js and using element ui framwork. I want to add few customization controls in it so that user can easily customize the whole plugin typography and other styles. I have added a color picker to change the colors of my plugin according to the user needs. now i want to add typography control but as i look into the element ui documentation there is no field for typography there is a component named as typography but we cannot use it.
I want to make it like the one in elementor which is a typography controls which has other controls as line height, letter spacing etc.I also have tried to make it custom but that does not working. it does not show any control in my panel.
I really need help in this one.
I tried to make it custom with vue js but it is not working. here is the vue code.
<template>
    <div class="typography-control">
        <!-- Font Family -->
        <div class="typography-control-section">
            <label for="font-family">Font Family</label>
            <el-select v-model="typography.font_family" placeholder="Select Font Family">
                <el-option v-for="font in fonts" :key="font" :value="font">
                    {{ font }}
                </el-option>
            </el-select>
        </div>

        <!-- Font Size -->
        <div class="typography-control-section">
            <label for="font-size">Font Size</label>
            <div class="size-unit-input">
                <el-input-number v-model="typography.font_size.size" :min="0" :precision="1"></el-input-number>
                <el-select v-model="typography.font_size.unit">
                    <el-option v-for="unit in units" :key="unit" :value="unit">
                        {{ unit }}
                    </el-option>
                </el-select>
            </div>
        </div>

        <!-- Font Weight -->
        <div class="typography-control-section">
            <label for="font-weight">Font Weight</label>
            <el-select v-model="typography.font_weight">
                <el-option v-for="(label, value) in fontWeights" :key="value" :value="value">
                    {{ label }}
                </el-option>
            </el-select>
        </div>

        <!-- Text Transform -->
        <div class="typography-control-section">
            <label for="text-transform">Text Transform</label>
            <el-select v-model="typography.text_transform">
                <el-option v-for="(label, value) in textTransforms" :key="value" :value="value">
                    {{ label }}
                </el-option>
            </el-select>
        </div>

        <!-- Font Style -->
        <div class="typography-control-section">
            <label for="font-style">Font Style</label>
            <el-select v-model="typography.font_style">
                <el-option v-for="(label, value) in fontStyles" :key="value" :value="value">
                    {{ label }}
                </el-option>
            </el-select>
        </div>

        <!-- Line Height -->
        <div class="typography-control-section">
            <label for="line-height">Line Height</label>
            <div class="size-unit-input">
                <el-input-number v-model="typography.line_height.size" :min="0" :precision="1"></el-input-number>
                <el-select v-model="typography.line_height.unit">
                    <el-option v-for="unit in units" :key="unit" :value="unit">
                        {{ unit }}
                    </el-option>
                </el-select>
            </div>
        </div>

        <!-- Letter Spacing -->
        <div class="typography-control-section">
            <label for="letter-spacing">Letter Spacing</label>
            <div class="size-unit-input">
                <el-input-number v-model="typography.letter_spacing.size" :min="0" :precision="1"></el-input-number>
                <el-select v-model="typography.letter_spacing.unit">
                    <el-option v-for="unit in units" :key="unit" :value="unit">
                        {{ unit }}
                    </el-option>
                </el-select>
            </div>
        </div>

        <!-- Color Picker -->
        <div class="typography-control-section">
            <label for="color">Text Color</label>
            <el-color-picker v-model="typography.color"></el-color-picker>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
    props: {
        value: {
            type: Object,
            default: () => ({}),
        },
        default: {
            type: Object,
            default: () => ({
                font_family: 'Arial',
                font_size: { size: 16, unit: 'px' },
                font_weight: '400',
                text_transform: '',
                font_style: 'normal',
                line_height: { size: 1.5, unit: '' },
                letter_spacing: { size: 0, unit: 'px' },
                color: '#000000',
            }),
        },
    },
    data() {
        return {
            typography: { ...this.default, ...this.value },
            fonts: ['Arial', 'Helvetica', 'Times New Roman', 'Verdana', 'Georgia', 'Tahoma', 'Courier New', 'Impact'],
            units: ['px', 'em', 'rem', '%'],
            fontWeights: {
                '': 'Default',
                '100': 'Thin (100)',
                '200': 'Extra Light (200)',
                '300': 'Light (300)',
                '400': 'Normal (400)',
                '500': 'Medium (500)',
                '600': 'Semi Bold (600)',
                '700': 'Bold (700)',
                '800': 'Extra Bold (800)',
                '900': 'Black (900)',
            },
            textTransforms: {
                '': 'Default',
                'uppercase': 'UPPERCASE',
                'lowercase': 'lowercase',
                'capitalize': 'Capitalize',
            },
            fontStyles: {
                '': 'Default',
                'normal': 'Normal',
                'italic': 'Italic',
                'oblique': 'Oblique',
            },
        };
    },
    watch: {
        value: {
            deep: true,
            immediate: true,
            handler(newVal) {
                this.typography = { ...this.default, ...newVal };
            },
        },
        typography: {
            deep: true,
            handler(newVal) {
                this.$emit('input', newVal);
            },
        },
    },
};
</script>

and here is the php code:
<?php

namespace WebinaneCommerce\Fields;

use WebinaneCommerce\Fields\Field;

class Typography extends Field
{
    /**
     * The field's component.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    public $component = 'typography-control';

    /**
     * Default typography settings.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $defaultSettings = [
        'font_family' => '',
        'font_size' => [
            'unit' => 'px',
            'size' => null
        ],
        'font_weight' => '',
        'text_transform' => '',
        'font_style' => '',
        'line_height' => [
            'unit' => 'px',
            'size' => null
        ],
        'letter_spacing' => [
            'unit' => 'px',
            'size' => null
        ],
        'color' => ''
    ];

    /**
     * Available font units.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $units = ['px', 'em', 'rem', '%'];

    /**
     * Available font weights.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $fontWeights = [
        '' => 'Default',
        '100' => 'Thin (100)',
        '200' => 'Extra Light (200)',
        '300' => 'Light (300)',
        '400' => 'Normal (400)',
        '500' => 'Medium (500)',
        '600' => 'Semi Bold (600)',
        '700' => 'Bold (700)',
        '800' => 'Extra Bold (800)',
        '900' => 'Black (900)'
    ];

    /**
     * Available text transforms.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $textTransforms = [
        '' => 'Default',
        'uppercase' => 'UPPERCASE',
        'lowercase' => 'lowercase',
        'capitalize' => 'Capitalize'
    ];

    /**
     * Available font styles.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $fontStyles = [
        '' => 'Default',
        'normal' => 'Normal',
        'italic' => 'Italic',
        'oblique' => 'Oblique'
    ];

    /**
     * Set default typography settings.
     *
     * @param array|null $settings
     * @return $this
     */
    public function default($settings = null)
    {
        // If settings is null or not an array, use the current default settings
        if ($settings === null || !is_array($settings)) {
            return $this->withMeta(['default' => $this->defaultSettings]);
        }

        // Merge the provided settings with the default settings
        $mergedSettings = array_merge($this->defaultSettings, $settings);
        
        return $this->withMeta(['default' => $mergedSettings]);
    }

    /**
     * Get available font units.
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function getUnits()
    {
        return $this->units;
    }

    /**
     * Get available font weights.
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function getFontWeights()
    {
        return $this->fontWeights;
    }

    /**
     * Get available text transforms.
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function getTextTransforms()
    {
        return $this->textTransforms;
    }

    /**
     * Get available font styles.
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function getFontStyles()
    {
        return $this->fontStyles;
    }

    public function saveTypographySettings($settings) {
        update_option('lifeline_donation_pro_typography', $settings);
    }
    
    public function getTypographySettings() {
        return get_option('lifeline_donation_pro_typography', $this->defaultSettings);
    }
    

    /**
     * Prepare the element for JSON serialization.
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function jsonSerialize()
    {
        return array_merge(parent::jsonSerialize(), [
            'defaultSettings' => $this->defaultSettings,
            'units' => $this->getUnits(),
            'fontWeights' => $this->getFontWeights(),
            'textTransforms' => $this->getTextTransforms(),
            'fontStyles' => $this->getFontStyles(),
        ]);
    }
}

